# Error airflow at start cause by sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

When i run `airflow standalone` after installing airflow i have that error

```
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, Add ``operator`` and ``queued_dttm`` to ``task_instance`` table
...
  File "/Users/hugochanteloup/code/.airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: operator
[SQL: ALTER TABLE task_instance ADD COLUMN operator VARCHAR(1000)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

python version 3.10.10
airflow 2.5.3
SQLAlchemy 1.4.47

I tried with another airflow version but same issue